# Error al exportar muchos datos desde la cmd en C

Tags: c

Ayuda, estoy tratando de exportar este codigo de C a un txt redireccionando la salida al momento de ejecutarlo desde la cmd, pero se cuelga yo creo que porque son demaciados datos (50.000) :s que debo hacer ?
inclusive en las variables

```
char *nombre_alumno[]

char *sexo_alumno[]
```

ni siquiera se ve el codigo en amarillo como en la foto, aparece todo en blanco como si no lo reconociese como un arreglo
** ahí en la imagen escribi que despues de los nombres y el sexo , seguian otros 50.000 valores.

```
    int main()
{
    char *nombre_alumno[] = {"Zina","Bartley","Primavera",.......,>>>50.000 datos mas<<,....};
    char *sexo_alumno[] = {"f","m","f","m","m","f",....,>>>50.000 datos mas<<<,....};
    int i;
    srand (getpid());       //Semilla para generar números aleatorios
    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(nombre_alumno)/sizeof(nombre_alumno[0]));i++)
    {
        printf("INSERT INTO ALUMNO VALUES (%d,'%s',%d,%d,'%s',%s);\n"
            ,Matricula_alumno,nombre_alumno[i],NUMEROS_AL_EDAD(),NUMEROS_AL_SEMESTRE(),sexo_alumno[i],NUMEROS_AL_CARRERA());
    }
}

int NUMEROS_AL_EDAD()
{
    int num;
    //numero = rand () % (N-M+1) + M;   // Este está entre M (valor minimo) y N (valor maximo)
    num = rand() % 54 + 17;  //Numeros aleatorios entre 17 y
    num = num + 1; 
    return num;
}
int NUMEROS_AL_SEMESTRE()
{
    int num;
    num = rand() % 11 + 1; //Numeros aleatorios entre 1 y 12
    num = num + 1; 
    return num;
}
int NUMEROS_AL_CARRERA()
{
    int num;
    num = rand() % 13 + 1; //Numeros aleatorios entre 1 y 13
    num = num + 1; 
    return num;
}
```

Comment: haz probado si realiza el procedimiento con pocos valores?

Comment: si, ahí funciona sin problemas

Comment: Pon `static` delante de tus variables `nombre_alumno[]` y `sexo_alumno[]`. O sacalas fuera del `main( )`.

Comment: Trauma Ninguno de los dos funcionó :l

Answer (score 0):

A mi ese `printf` no me gusta un pelo:

```
printf("INSERT INTO ALUMNO VALUES (%d,'%s',%d,%d,'%s',%s);\n"
       ,Matricula_alumno,nombre_alumno[i],NUMEROS_AL_EDAD(),NUMEROS_AL_SEMESTRE(),sexo_alumno[i],NUMEROS_AL_CARRERA());
```

Si lo miramos más de cerca:

```
printf("INSERT INTO ALUMNO VALUES (%d,'%s',%d,%d,'%s',%s);\n",
//                                                    ^^
       Matricula_alumno,
       nombre_alumno[i],
       NUMEROS_AL_EDAD(),
       NUMEROS_AL_SEMESTRE(),
       sexo_alumno[i],
       NUMEROS_AL_CARRERA());
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   int NUMEROS_AL_CARRERA()
// ^^^
{
}
```

Resumiendo... `printf` va a tratar el 6º parámetro como si fuese una cadena de caracteres y sin embargo le estás pasando un entero... o bien te acaba imprimendo basura o el programa acaba cascando... a los Sistemas Operativos modernos no les suele hacer demasiada gracia que accedas a memoria que no te pertenece.